# Feedback about downvote on "Extending IPrincipal.IsInRole()"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I have a question about my Code Review Stack Exchange post: [Extending IPrincipal.IsInRole()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188486/extending-iprincipal-isinrole)

I got a downvote, I can understand that, it's my first post here but not my first SE site. The high rep user who downvoted did not actually give me a direct answer to the reasons behind the downvote, he suggested that I read the on-topic page, which I did before posting and I made sure to follow all what's written there to my best knowledge.

The help page says about things [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you can answer "yes" to all of the following questions, then your question is on-topic for Code Review:

Here's the questions:

> **Is code included directly in my question?**

My answer is yes, my post has the code.

> **Am I an author or maintainer of the code?**

Yes it's me who wrote it.

> **Is it actual code from a project**

Yes, copied directly from my project with no alterations.

> **To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?**

Yes it does.

> **Do I want the code to be good code?**

Yes, that's why I asked here.

> **Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?**

Yes I do, that's why I asked.

All the answers are yes to the questions which should determine if my question is on-topic or not, I have no issues with the downvote. My issue is, if I still missed something, why didn't the high rep user point me directly to the issue instead of spending the time making comments as riddles, just point me to the exact problem so I can fix the problem in my post, or tell me it's off-topic and I will simply delete the question and everyone will be happy.

I think comments are meant to ask further stuff about the question, or explain why the question is bad and not to make riddles .. am I missing something here?

A random example from another SE site, a new user posts something, a high-rep user simply welcomes him, adds a *direct* comment to the new user explaining why his answer needs an edit, the users says thank you and do that. Everyone is happy, SE got improved a bit, new users passing by read it and learn something, the post is edited and improved, no riddles, no smart comments, no showing off that someone knows better than you, etc. etc.:

[image: sample]

**Please can someone tell me directly what is wrong with my question** so I can avoid it in the future without unintentionally insulting someone. I'll really appreciate that.

Comment: General advice: Don't delete any post just because a few high-rep users says it's off-topic. Code Review has **a lot** of grey areas were some people think something is on-topic, others will think it is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You have 1 close vote, too (emphasis mine)

> Lacks concrete context: Code Review requires concrete code from a
>   project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that
>   code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated
>   code, **and generic best practices** are outside the scope of this site.

I can't speak for anyone, I wouldn't have given you a downvote, but all I can surmise is that you asked

> Is this the right approach?

*Technically* that's not the correct question for this site, more of a "can I improve my algorithm or am I reinventing the wheel?" There's a tag for that, too [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel).

*I* don't think there's anything wrong with your question.

All that being said, the user you are referring to is in Germany and may not have seen your remarks yet.

Comment: General advice: I wouldn't recommend users adding too much value into the exact formulation of *"Is this the right approach?"* vs. *"Can I improve this code?"*

Comment: Yeah, me neither

Comment: "**It's OK to ask 'Does this code follow common best practices?'**, but not 'What is the best practice regarding X?'" - Help Center. I think asking "Is this the right approach?" falls more into the first category.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone, I think this site has a great user base.

However, I have learned that I should look into the user's profile before getting into any sort of argument, this should help me decide whether to simply ignore, or try to continue.

The user who downvoted seems to be a regular downvoter, so I wasn't being targeted or anything, it wasn't my mistake (nor his), it's just who he is and I respect that.

I checked the top 10 users or so, and I found out that the average up/downvote ratio is around 1:10 (more upvotes), while this particular user has the opposite (more downvotes).

[image: votes]

Had I checked his account earlier, I would have simply avoided this post and the whole argument. I kinda like the way profiles are shown here, you basically build up a very good impression about the user after spending a few minutes checking the vote cast, the self introduction and how "long it is", the answers, the questions, the comments, the edits, the badges, etc.